# Spring Data JDBC: No such property found for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am a beginner in Spring Data JDBC. I am following Spring in action 6th edition and have created the repository as follows:

```
package com.springinaction.tacocloud;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface IngredientRepository extends CrudRepository<Ingredient, String>{

    public Optional<Ingredient> getById(String id);
    
    public Iterable<Ingredient> getIngredients();
    
    public Ingredient save(Ingredient ingredient);
}
```

And I have injected this repository in my controller.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {
    
    protected IngredientRepository ingredientRepo;
    
    public DesignTacoController(IngredientRepository ingredientRepo) {
        this.ingredientRepo = ingredientRepo;
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        Iterable<Ingredient> ingredientsFromJdbc = ingredientRepo.getIngredients();
        //converting Iterable returned by JdbcTemplate to a List
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
        ingredientsFromJdbc.forEach(ingredients::add);
        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
    }
.......................................................................
```

For invoking the method getIngredients() in the controller it throws the following exception

```
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'getIngredients' found for type 'Ingredient'!
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is no such method getIngredients() provided by CrudRepository.

Comment: Silly me. I replaced the method with findAll() and it worked. This is a good point for me to note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the method `getIngredients()` and use `findAll()` (provided by the super interface) instead.

You should also remove the other methods, because they are already provided by the super interface

- `save()` <- provided by `CrudRepository`
- `getById()` <- `CrudRepository` provide `Optional<T> findById(ID id);`
- `getIngredients` <- `CrudRepository` provide `Iterable<T> findAll();`